# 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIKeyCommand'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

My app is crashing when I try to display another view controller. It does work correctly when the iOS SDK is set to 7.0 and I am targeting iOS 7.0. But I need the app to target iOS 6.0. UIKit is (obviously) declared in the imports. The UITableViewController I am trying to present works perfectly fine as far as I'm aware - I created it for another app, using XCode 4.6.3, targeting 6.0 and it compiled without error (as does this one) but it also displays without crashing.

I could provide code, code which does nothing more than present the table view controller using a modal transition, but I even went to the point of connecting a UIButton to the UITableViewController - it worked on iOS 7, but not 6. It's my belief that when I compile with the iOS 6.1 SDK, it should be using iOS 6.1 frameworks?

[UIKeyCommand is only available in iOS 7 and later, according to this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/Reference/Reference.html) That gives me reason to believe that it is using the iOS 7.0 frameworks even though the iOS 6.1 SDK has been specified.

I've tagged this with the xcode tag as I believe it could possibly be caused by xcode incorrectly searching for the specified SDK's frameworks.

Comment: If it's not available on iOS 7 than you should not use it there - that's the reason for crash. You have to prepare a different way for handling iOS 6.

Comment: It is only available on iOS 7. I am not building for iOS, nor am I using any iOS 7 specific classes or frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and here is what i did to solve it:

I opened the `Storyboard` as `Source Code` and searched for the tag : `keyCommands` , I found a tag similar to

```
<keyCommands> <keyCommand/> </keyCommands>
```

and i deleted it.

After that i runned the app in `iOS 6 & 7` and it worked with no problem.

Let me know if this works on your app too!

Cheers!